# Why is `ld` failing to link this program?

Tags: c, xcode

What is this command not linking my file to the library I want to use?

```
> ld elements.o ~/Code/MyLibraries/usr/local/lib/libexpat.a
```

Backstory:

So...I am a C newbie and am trying to use `libexpat` in one of my projects.

I was able to compile the library and get it to work. Moreover, I was also able to get the sample programs to run. Fantastic. Now I want to modify the sample programs and see how far I go.

This is where I get stuck because I don't really understand how the compilation works. `./configure` and `make` do a lot behind the scenes.

Right now `ld` doesn't find `(xmlparse.o)` in `libexpat.a` when linking the library (see full output below)...however I know the library works because I can run it in XCode.I did drag and drop it there for now.

I would love to get this to build from the command line so that I know what XCode is doing behind the scenes to make this all work.

According to this [article](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)...`ld` is supposed to work but it's failing me.

Trying to reverse engineer the Makefile that built the sample file is also a bit confusing and I can't understand it. Here what is in the Makefile when I grep it with the example program [`elements.c`](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/blob/6b1996334139e6d175d2bb7ceda6a30b0342c418/expat/examples/elements.c):

```
elements_SOURCES = elements.c
elements_LDADD = ../lib/libexpat.la
elements$(EXEEXT): $(elements_OBJECTS) $(elements_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_elements_DEPENDENCIES)
```

Can you help me figure out the command? What are XCode/Make doing behind the scenes that allows this to work?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___assert_rtn", referenced from:
      _XML_GetParsingStatus in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _doProlog in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "___bzero", referenced from:
      _lookup in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
      _lookup in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _storeAtts in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _findEncoding in libexpat.a(xmltok.o)
      _findEncodingNS in libexpat.a(xmltok.o)
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
      _lookup in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _storeAtts in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _findEncoding in libexpat.a(xmltok.o)
      _findEncodingNS in libexpat.a(xmltok.o)
  "___stderrp", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
      _startParsing in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "___stdinp", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
  "_arc4random_buf", referenced from:
      _startParsing in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_fprintf", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
      _startParsing in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_fread", referenced from:
      _main in elements.o
  "_free", referenced from:
      _parserCreate in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_getenv", referenced from:
      _startParsing in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_malloc", referenced from:
      _parserCreate in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_memcmp", referenced from:
      _doContent in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_memcpy", referenced from:
      _parserInit in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _XML_SetEncoding in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _XML_Parse in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _XML_GetBuffer in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _poolGrow in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _storeRawNames in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      _storeAtts in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
      ...
  "_memmove", referenced from:
      _XML_GetBuffer in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_memset", referenced from:
      _handleUnknownEncoding in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_printf", referenced from:
      _startElement in elements.o
  "_putchar", referenced from:
      _startElement in elements.o
  "_realloc", referenced from:
      _parserCreate in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
  "_strcmp", referenced from:
      _startParsing in libexpat.a(xmlparse.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Usually one is calling `ld` via the C compiler which adds to the argument provided those needed for start up code and linking the standard library.  `gcc elements.o ~/Code/MyLibraries/usr/local/lib/libexpat.a` or `clang elements.o ~/Code/MyLibraries/usr/local/lib/libexpat.a` should do.

Comment: @AProgrammer - Yes! Can confirm this worked to compile. Still a bit frustrated that `ld` dosen't work when it seems like it should. To the other user: it was compiled on & for the same machine I'm using.

Comment: @ovatsug25, how should it guest the additional arguments it should use?  With `gcc` (I don't know about `clang` and I'm too lazy to check if it is the same), `-v` should output the precise command used.

Comment: @AProgrammer - ran `-v` and was able to get the command used. PS — On macOS `gcc` is aliased to `clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the full command to get the linker to work:

```
ld -o my_linked_elements elements.o ~/Code/MyLibraries/usr/local/lib/libexpat.a \
   -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```